# watir issue with displaying new dropdown menu

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

manually clicking on tab(anchor tag) its displaying drop down menu(unordered list) with watir element is locating but drop down menu is not displaying

HTML

```
<ul> 
  <li id="NetworkAnalysisTabPanel__ext-comp-1038" class=" x-tab-strip-menuable x-tab-strip-active "> 
    <a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
    <a class="x-tab-strip-menu" onclick="return false;"></a>
    <a></a>
    <a class="x-tab-right" onclick="return false;" href=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Tried the following line of code to click on the tab

```
$ff.div(:id,"NetworkAnalysisTabPanel").div(:index,1).div(:index,1).ul(:index,1).li(:index,1).link(:index,2).fire_event("onClick")
```

I am using watir 1.6.6 version

Comment: you'll need to provide some sample html of your app

Comment: It would also be most helpful to know (especially since you are using index a lot) if this is Watir, Watir-Webdriver, and which version (of either or each)

Comment: I am using watir 1.6.6 version

Comment: <ul>                                                             <li id="NetworkAnalysisTabPanel__ext-comp-1038" class=" x-tab-strip-menuable x-tab-strip-active ">
    <a class="x-tab-strip-close" onclick="return false;"></a>
    <a class="x-tab-strip-menu" onclick="return false;"></a>
    <a></a>
    <a class="x-tab-right" onclick="return false;" href=""></a>
</li>                                                               </ul>

Comment: dude, EDIT the original question... don't make others do it for you.  removed prior downvote since he finally responded to the comment reequests

Answer (score 0):

Firstly since your HTML sample that you provided does not include the element you are using in the command you attmepted, it's hard to know where that might be going wrong.  Secondly since the code you provided does have a div with a unique ID present, why not start there instead of with an outer container.

I think the problem is that you are using

```
.fire_event("onCLick")
```

However the code is monitoring for an event named "onclick" (all lower case)

Try using

```
.fire_event("onclick")
```

or if you have not already, perhaps just

```
.click
```

and see if that works for you

Also, I'd seriously recommend you upgrade to a more current version of Watir.. 1.6.6 is pretty behind the times.

Update:  that html code is starting to look very familiar to me, if this is the same basic control from the other two questions you've posted so far, then try firing the 'onmousedown' event against the element that invokes the menu and see if that works